# QFileDialog not closing after file selection

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a simple function that opens a file dialog using pyqt6 to select a file.
The function works, but the dialog hangs after being called and I'm not sure why it's not getting automatically closed when the file is selected.

```
def ui_find_file(title=None, initialdir=None, file_type=None):
  import os
  from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

  app = QApplication([])
  file_dialog = QFileDialog()
  file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFile)

  if file_type:
      filter = f"{file_type} files (*.{file_type})"
      file_dialog.setNameFilter(filter)
  else:
      file_dialog.setNameFilter("All files (*);;")

  if initialdir is None:
      initialdir = os.getcwd()
  elif initialdir == '~':
      initialdir = os.path.expanduser('~')

  file_dialog.setDirectory(initialdir)

  if title:
      file_dialog.setWindowTitle(title)

  if file_dialog.exec():
      file_path = file_dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
      print(f"Selected {file_path}")
      file_dialog.deleteLater()  # Clean up the file dialog window
      app.quit()  # Exit the event loop
      return file_path
  else:
      print("No file selected")
      file_dialog.deleteLater()  # Clean up the file dialog window
      app.quit()  # Exit the event loop
      return None
```

When I try the first lines in the command line

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

app = QApplication([])
file_dialog = QFileDialog()
file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFile)
```

and I use either `file_dialog.open()` or `file_dialog.exec()`, I can select a file and the dialog closes without freezing the python instance. I don't even have to call `file_dialog.deleteLater()` for it to close itself.

When I try to use this from another script, for example doing:

```
from utils import ui_find_file
ui_find_file()
```

It produces the freezing behavior.

#### Updates on things I have tried but didn't work

I am running this in python 3.10, Ubuntu 20.04, from a terminal.

- I have tried using `destroy()` instead of `destroyLater()`.
- I have tried using `app.processEvents()` below `destroy()` with `del(app)`

The reason I am creating `app = QApplication([])` was because when I didn't, I got `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget` (which I can reproduce by commenting out the line)

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from utils import ui_find_file
>>> ui_find_file()
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Does this happen using the *exact* scripts shown above (specifically, the last one)? I am not able to reproduce the issue (at least on Linux), but be aware that calling `app.quit()` is quite pointless: you've *never* entered the app event loop (`app.exec()` was never called), so there's nothing to "quit".

Comment: @musicamante Yes, this happens running exactly those lines. Also, you are right,  `app.quit()` is not doing anything here. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @musicamante Just to clarify, you saved `ui_find_files` into `utils.py` and use it using `from utils import ui_find_file` followed by `ui_find_file()` and you get the normal window behavior, which closes after selecting files?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I only used a different file name, but that's irrelevant. About that, ensure that you are not actually using a *different* `utils.py` script (maybe by running the script from another path, which contains *another* `utils.py` with different code). Also, are you doing this from the IDE or from a terminal? Consider using `file_dialog.destroy()` instead of `deleteLater()` (which would require the app event loop), and eventually call `app.processEvents()` *and* `del app` before returning.

Comment: Also, can you clarify the exact reason for the code above? Note that you should normally not need to create a QApplication more than once, and you should instead create *a single one* and eventually reuse it, for instance, doing `app = QApplication.instance()` `if not app:` `app = QApplication([])`.

Comment: @musicamante Please see edits, yes I'm positive `utils.py` is the correct one since making changes in that file changes behavior in the console (such as commenting `app=QApplication([])`).

Comment: I didn't say that you should not create the application, but you should not create *more than once*; please read my above comment more carefully. Also note that running a script is *not* exactly the same as importing and executing: PyQt has an "input hook" that allows running the QApplication event loop without calling `app.exec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code as follows to quit when being called from another script

```
def ui_find_file(title=None, initialdir=None, file_type=None):
    """
    Find a file using a GUI.
    :param title: Title of the dialog.
    :param initialdir: Initial directory.
    :param file_type: File type.
    :return: File path.
    """
    import os
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
        is_new_instance = True
    else:
        is_new_instance = False

    if title is None:
        title = 'Find a file'
    if initialdir is None:
        initialdir = os.getcwd()
    if file_type is None:
        file_filter = 'All files (*.*)'
    else:
        file_filter = f"{file_type} files (*.{file_type})"

    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, title, initialdir, file_filter)

    if file_path:
        # no multiple files for now...file_path will be a string
        #file_path = file_path[0]
        print(f"Selected {file_path}")
        result = file_path
    else:
        print("No file selected")
        result = None

    if is_new_instance:
        app.quit()

    return result
```

In this modification, we added a boolean variable is_new_instance to determine whether the `QApplication` instance was newly created in this function. If it was, we quit the `QApplication` instance by calling `app.quit()` after the file dialog is closed. This ensures that the event loop is properly managed and should prevent the script from hanging after the file selection.